# Backing up OpenLDAP in Windows environment

Tags: windows, openldap, database-backup

I need to find a concept how to backup OpenLDAP data (the data directory) in a windows environment. I googled around a bit and found: https://github.com/elmar/ldap-git-backup. But this framework is for Debian environments.

Does anybody know a framework for Windows environments? Does anybody know alternative concepts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your safest option in general is to use the slapcat utility. This will produce a portable file containing all the information you need to reconstitute your server.

The concept is:

- run slapcat to take the backup (i.e. slapcat -n 1 -l backuplocation\backupfile.ldif)
- transport the backupfile.ldif to a backup location
- done

This can be done with a scheduled task easily enough

The important details of actually taking the backups depend on how you installed OpenLDAP on the windows system.  A quick search indicates a number of windows ports of OpenLDAP.

How is LDAP setup?

- slapd.conf
- cn=config

What database are you using?  bdb and hdb are safe to slapcat against while running

Sorry, but your question is pretty open ended.

Comment: The LDAP is setup via slapd.conf and the databse is bdb. Slapcat is a very good idea. Can ldapsearch/add also be used in that case? After doing some research, I decided that the following is a suitable approach: 
1. Set up replication system (Domain Controller Master, Backup, and Slave)
2. There are two ways to back up periodically the data: 
   1. Shut down slapd on the slave, copy the database files out, then start it back up.
   2. Using slapcat or ldapsearch.
The data is also exported into xml files. To backup xml files, I would use git. suitable approach?